# Scale vector to sum to 1 while keeping signs

Tags: optimization, vectors

In order to scale a vector $w$ with postive and negative elements to sum to 1, $\frac{w}{\sum w}$ does the job. But if $\sum w < 0$, the elements of the scaled vector $w_s$ change signs. Is it possible to scale such a vector to sum to 1 while keeping the signs of the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(w_j)$ be given.  You want to find a constant $c$ with $\sum_j c\ w_j=1$.  The unique solution is $c=1/\sum_j w_j$, so you cannot preserve signs if $\sum_j w_j < 0$.